# AWS EC2 Windows UserData script not running

Tags: amazon-web-services, batch-file, amazon-ec2, user-data

I have a windows batch script that runs locally and also runs on the EC2 when I run it manually. However, when I try to launch an ec2 via the CLI and I feed in the script in the user-data parameter it does not run.

This is the script:

```
for /l %%x in (20171101,1,20171102) do (
start "S3Copy" C:\Progra~1\Amazon\AWSCLI\aws s3 cp 
s3://bucket1/%%x s3://bucket2/%%x --recursive
)

echo waiting
:loop
timeout 1 >nul
tasklist /v |find "S3Copy" >nul && goto :loop
echo all of them are finished

shutdown.exe /s /t 00
```

When I pass it into UserData I surround it with:

> [script] [/script] (angle brackets)

Yet it does not run like this.

As I have stated, I can log into the same Ec2 that was launched and I can run the script manually and works as expected.

I will say, when I log in manually I use a specific user, when I launch from cli, it uses a specific Key file, which could use a different user, but the .aws config is set up for all users on that AMI.

What might be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an IAM Role or an IAM User? More secure to use a role and it will potentially solve your problem: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html

Also, take a look at this - there are a few more nuances for Windows as opposed to Linux: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have spoken with amazon about this and in essence all the planets have to align for this to work in windows. I'm taking a different route. Still using above script but with a loader in the ami that gets the script from s3 and runs it.